# parameter is incorrect error when giving values more than the maximum length in webedit field

Tags: qtp

I am doing automation using qtp tool and m stucked in between of script.

I am inputing the value in webedit and it maximum length is 20 and can accept only numeric values and when I am giving more than 20 characters and qtp is throwing parameter is incorrect error
 somebody pls help I can I handle this error in my script only
thanx in advance

Comment: What help are you looking for? Isn't QTP's behaviour correct? It's a error inputting more than the allowed number of characters.

Comment: I think he us stumbling over QTP complaining about the attempt to enter a string longer than the maximum allowed characters for this edit field. He probably expected that QTP would emulate the input of more than 20 characters, and the app would ignore all text after the 20th character. Many people attempt to create a test checking if after the input, there are 20 characters in the field, truncated correctly, and the error QTP gives is then counter-intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what kind of help you're looking for, [surely](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KM2K7sV-K74) this is what you should expect from a testing tool, to give an error when a step that cannot be performed is requested.

If you want to do something else when such an error happens you can do one of two things.

1. Add a [recovery scenario](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/qtp/qtp_recovery_scenarios.htm) that treats this case
2. Override `WebEdit.Set` to do what you want (using the *Function Definition Generator*)

Like this:

```vbs
Public Function CheckedSet(ByRef obj, ByVal value)
       maxLen = obj.GetROProperty("max length")
       valLen = Len(value)
       If maxLen > valLen Then
        obj.Set value   
       Else 
        ' Do whatever you want to do here
        Reporter.ReportEvent micWarning, "Set", "Lengh of '" & value &"' (" & valLen &") is longer than maximal length of edit field: " & maxLen        
       End If
End Function
RegisterUserFunc "WebEdit", "Set", "CheckedSet"
```